# Redux-React app: How to remake my app that instead of mapStateToProps and matchDispatch there were useSelector and useDispatch?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have class component App. But I need to remake my component to functional component and remake my app that instead of mapStateToProps and matchDispatch there were useSelector and useDispatch. But i never worked with useSelector and useDispatch. So please help me.Component implement like button, when you click on it - number increment per unit.

Index.js:

```
//action
const plusLike = index => ({
    type: "PLUS_LIKE",
    payload:index
});

//reducer
const reducer = (state={like:0},action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case "PLUS_LIKE":
            return Object.assign({},state, {
               like: action.payload
            });
        default:
            return state
    }
};

//it must be functional component
class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
        <div>
           <button onClick={index => this.props.onPlusLike(this.props.onLike+1)}>Like</button>
          {this.props.onLike}   
        </div>                         
        );
    }
}

//mapStateToProps
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    onLike: state.propReducer.like
});

//matchDispatchToProps
const matchDispatchToProps = dispatch =>({
    onPlusLike: index => dispatch(plusLike(index))
});

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    propReducer:reducer
});

const ConnectApp = connect(
     mapStateToProps,
     matchDispatchToProps
)(App);

const store = createStore(allReducers);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectApp/>
    </Provider>,
document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation? What have you tried?

Comment: @bytor, first of all read this documentation - https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks
After that try to solve ploblem yourself and then update your question with snippets to show how you tried to solve the ploblem.

Comment: @Dennis Vash The documentation is difficult for a beginner to understand. I have long understood that the best way to understand something is to do what you already know with a new tool and conversely to remake what you don’t know into what you already know

Comment: @aopanasenko The documentation is difficult for a beginner to understand. I have long understood that the best way to understand something is to do what you already know with a new tool and conversely to remake what you don’t know into what you already know

Comment: Use Hooks: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks However, be aware that they do not work in classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can swap `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` with `useSelector` and `useDispatch` in `React`. Note that this does not work with classes.

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import plusLike from 'your-actions'

function App() {
  const likes = useSelector((state) => state.propReducer.like);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={(index) => dispatch(plusLike(likes+1))}>Like</button>
      {likes}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

Comment: However you should note that redux hooks do not work in classes

Comment: Ah, thanks. Should I add it as a note in the answer too? @BenBieler

Comment: @Ajin Kabeer No, because I dont know what to write in ```const ConnectApp```
Can you try change in sandbox- forked and send me link to new sandbox?
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-napier-6ddfb?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Hey @bytor, Here you go, [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-tharp-sbqke?file=/src/index.js).

Comment: @Ajin Kabeer thanks! That is, if I write functional component I dont must use method ```connect```?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The new redux `hooks` APIs allows us to subscribe to redux store and dispatch actions without wrapping our components with `connect()`.